# NODEJS Include variable from POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, ejs

Hi I want to display information from array brought from database into a ejs/html page, and I'm getting a 'is not defined' error...

[Error I'm getting /CLICK TO SEE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i0kR.png)

Then I have a POST method displaying in console all that is in array such as:

```
  app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  datacollection.insertOne(req.body)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
      res.redirect('/quotes')
      db.collection('datacollection').find().toArray()
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
  // ...
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
});
```

and on the html/ejs page I have a include that is:

```
'<%= datacollection %>'
```

I am trying to pass the value via:

```
app.get('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('datacollection').find().toArray()
    .then(results => {
      res.render('quotes.ejs', { datacollection: results })
    })
    .catch(/* ... */)

})
```

how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first in your get request you should type

```
res.render("quotes")
```

instead of

```
res.render("quotes.ejs")
```

which is wrong.

I assume that in your code you have public directory and views directory ,in order to work properly and your code be able to see them.As you are working in a database like mongo in post request you must save new result and then redirect to a route

```
result.save();
res.redirect("/");
```

In get request try this

```
*your_db_model*.find({"result": {$ne: null}}, function(err, results){
      if (results) {
        res.render("quotes", {datacollection: results});
      }
```

Also you have array so you must print it in quote.ejs like this

```
<%  datacollection.forEach(function(data){ %>

    <h1><%=data.title%></h1>
<% } %>
```

I hope this will help you find some of the errors in your code.Send again if your code still not works.

Comment: Hi! Thank you ever so much for the help!

I am now trying to access the object object shown in the page, and with this code:

<%  datacollection.forEach(function(data){ %>

    <h1><%=data.name%></h1>
<% } %>

I am getting an error:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in C:\Users\FT\Desktop\foobase-master\project\html\pages\quotes.ejs while compiling ejs

Tried a few changes, but haven't managed, still stuck at object object... 

Whats wrong?

Comment: In the end you should add a parenthesis with the closing bracket,like this: <% }) %>

Comment: It gives me an error: 

datacollection.forEach is not a function

...

Comment: Are you sure you dont have any typo errors in quotes.ejs and app.js file?Also you changed your get request like i wrote above.Check also your db via terminal or gui to see if you find collection and elements inside.